# Selecting all connected nodes to a given node and listing relationships in py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo

I have recently started working on `py2neo` for `neo4j` database, and **avoiding** using `cypher` queries.

I am looking forward to know how to select all the nodes connected to a given node and select the relationships between this given node and connected nodes. Since documentation on this is not sufficient, someone who has worked on it may help.

I know that we can select a node using

```
node = selector.select("nodetype",key=value)
```

where

```
selector = NodeSelector(graph)
```

and this will list all the nodes which are of type "nodetype" and have the key-value property pair. Can we use this selector to select nodes connected to a given node and list the relationships between the given node and connected nodes? Or is there any method other than `selector` available?

Comment: You can use py2neo and Cypher together. Why would you abandon cypher? There are going to be scenarios where you cannot count on py2neo to have a suitable function.